# Servidor público ou servidor do público?

Tags: etimologia, concordância-nominal

A categoria de funcionários do governo regidos pela [Lei Federal 8112/90](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/l8112cons.htm) possui esta designação: servidor público.

Entretanto este termo designa um servidor que é lotado no setor público (Administração pública). Por isso que levanto esta questão, não seria o termo servidor do (setor) público mais adequado?

Conjugando para o feminino esta ideia fica ainda mais clara: *servidora do público* e não *servidora pública*. No primeiro caso termo *público* é um complemento do termo oculto *setor*, melhor colocado que o segundo, *pública* que é um adjetivo para a servidora.

Resumindo: público não seria um atributo do seu regime de trabalho do servidor e não do indivíduo?

Comment: Talvez a situação ficaria bem resolvida se houvesse um recurso na língua portuguesa de _concordância nominal indireta_. Como seria isto? O _funcionário_ trabalha em um _setor de atividade_ (atributo de funcionário), e este por sua vez é _público_ (atributo de setor). Por esta relação indireta, poderia concordar o atributo do atributo ao substantivo. Seria um bom tratado para a língua portuguesa: *Concordância Nominal Indireta*

Answer (score 1):

Não seria mais adequado porque o adjetivo público já significa (segundo o Priberam):

> 3. Relativo à governação ou administração de um país. ≠ PARTICULAR, PRIVADO

Da mesma forma temos *cargos públicos*, *direito público*, e por aí adiante.

Comment: Estes termos: _cargos_, _direitos_, não deixam dúvida disto que você colocou. Mas quando se aplica a uma pessoa, evitaria o entendimento desta outra significação de público: _relativo ou pertencente a um povo, a uma coletividade_. No feminino esta ideia fica bem clara: a servidora  pública. Neste caso pública aparece como um adjetivo que concorda com o substantivo servidora, quando devia concordar com o setor que ela trabalha.

Comment: Fazendo uma analogia com a resposta: funcionário _da iniciativa privada_, veja que o termo _privada_ concordou com _iniciativa_ e não com _funcionário_

Comment: @gwarah Diria que é impossível alguém ouvir _funcionário público_ (o termo correspondente mais usado em Portugal) e pensar que significasse outra coisa que não alguém que trabalhasse para o Estado. Vejo pouco potencial de ambiguidade. Mas mesmo que o haja, isso não invalida que _servidor público_ esteja correto, dado _público_ estar a ser usado num significado dicionarizado -- não há portanto qualquer elisão, como mencionas na pergunta, e o adjetivo concorda em género com o nome, como é normal em português.

Comment: entendo o que você diz. O termo _funcionário (ou servidor) público_ se popularizou de forma a não deixar dúvida no significado. Por outro lado não estou tratando o caso como um erro gramatical. É apenas uma questão comparativa com o termo _privado_ que, como coloquei no meu post anterior, não seguiu a mesma analogia. Ora, se o termo _privado_ concorda com setor e não com funcionário e é _normal_, então entendo que o mesmo se aplicaria ao termo _público_. Neste último caso não seria uma elisão mas uma variante com uma base gramatical e não pelo entendimento popular.

Comment: Essa falta de simetria com privado que referes agora, não a encontro na pergunta. É verdade que _funcionário privado_ é mais incomum do que _funcionário do [setor] privado_ (já _empresa privada_ é muito comum), mas mesmo este último termo é menos usado do que o termo _trabalhador do [setor] privado_, que contrasta com _trabalhador do [setor] público_, não _trabalhador público_.

Comment: @gwarah são também convenções linguísticas e jurídicas. Por exemplo na Constituição portuguesa, a simples palavra `funcionário` refere-se a funcionário [do setor] público.

Comment: @Artefacto, esta simetria ocorre mas com uma "ajuda" do termo intermediário. Ex: _funcionário [do setor] privado_ e _funcionária [da iniciativa] privada_. Se possível, por favor veja um comentário que postei após a pergunta que pode ser uma proposta de solução para esta questão.

Comment: Entendo @JoãoPimentelFerreira, não deixa de ser um fator que consolide a primeira hipótese esta base jurídica. Mas em outros casos que acredito não ter, recai igualmente nesta questão:  _trabalhador [do setor] privado_ e _trabalhadora [da iniciativa] privada_. A concordância de gênero se dá de forma indireta com ajuda destes termos ocultos.

Answer (score 1):

Usamos a denominação "servidor público" no Brasil há décadas, e isso nunca foi questionado.  **Quando um termo é consagrado pelo uso e torna-se idiomático, não importa mais se é correto ou não, se faz sentido ou não.**

Comment: Em pt-PT dizemos `funcionário público`. Em qualquer caso tem toda a razão, pois poderíamos dizer `funcionário do público`. Em Inglês dizem como no Brasil, *public servant*. Em Alemão têm uma abordagem com referência ao "instituto" (*Amt*), dizendo *Beamter*, ou seja, "aquele que trabalha no instituto".

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira  Também usamos "funcionário público" no Brasil, inclusive há mais tempo do que "servidor público".  Em Inglês eu conheço como "civil servant".

Comment: Por favor, vejam um comentário que postei após a pergunta. Aborda um tema que pode ser a solução desta questão. Opiniões são bem vindas.

Comment: @Centaurus, o fato de estar consagrado e nunca ter sido questionado não significa que não possa ser modifica. Vemos com frequência em nossa língua aparecerem palavras, termos e expressões novas e igualmente outras que eram até então populares  caírem em desuso. A língua é algo dinâmico que se modifica frequentemente.

Comment: @gwarah "não significa que não possa ser modifica."  Eu não disse isso.  Pode ser modificado sim, e a nova forma cair no uso popular. Mas não foi.

Comment: Não fiz alusão a isto @Centaurus, foi só um contraponto para frisar estas constantes mudanças e revisões linguísticas que passamos. Tais mudanças atingem até termos tidos por "canônicos" do idioma.

Answer (score 1):

> público não seria um atributo do seu regime de trabalho do servidor e não do indivíduo?

Não, *público* seria um adjetivo que significa *da população* ou *do governo* na expressão "servidor público" que, portanto, é equivalente a "servidor governamental".

O regime de trabalho me parece ser uma característica do indivíduo **enquanto trabalhador**. Termos análogos seriam *funcionário noturno*, *servidor aposentado*, *trabalhador informal*, etc.

Um paralelo poderia ser com os nomes "cor de rosa" e apenas "rosa" para a cor. Ambos são corretos.

Comment: sim e não. Concordo no caso de _servidor aposentado_, que é um atributo direto de servidor. No caso de _trabalhador informal_, o adjetivo serve para os 2 gêneros. No primeiro caso podemos ter uma relação indireta do tipo atributo de atributo: _servidor do setor público_ e _servidora da gestão pública_. Conseguimos "forçar" esta concordância flexionando o atributo intermediário. Por favor, veja um comentário que fiz após a pergunta que pode ser um meio de resolver a questão.

Comment: @gwarah Ainda me parece desnecessário, uma questão de preferência, como os nomes "cor de rosa" e apenas "rosa" para a cor. O *público* seria um adjetivo que significa *da população* ou *do governo* na expressão "servidor público". Incluí esta sugestões na resposta.

Comment: Este exemplo foi interessante @stafusa, mas ainda aí cabe uma diferença. O termo composto _cor de rosa_, pode ser entendido por _cor similar à rosa_, ou seja, similar é um termo que não é atributo de cor mas comparativo a rosa. Além disso, não sofre flexão de gênero. O objetivo da minha pergunta foi explorar a concordância e flexão de termos de forma indireta, que de certa forma supoe um atributo oculto. Até onde eu sei, não existe uma regra gramatical nestes caso, fica então definido pela "jurisprudência" do que está consagrado.